# How to use start and pause buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have a Start and a Pause button on my gui. When I click start, it executes method run() from another class and I want to be able to pause the execution however I can't click the pause button while the program is running and the pause button is only clickable when run() finishes.

How do I make pause button clickable while run() is being executed?

Comment: I guess the reason why the pause button is not clickable is that the Event Dispatch Thread is running the long execution rather than something like SwingWorker which spawn another thread for execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click start, it executes method run() from another class and I
>   want to be able to pause the execution however I can't click the pause
>   button while the program is running and the pause button is only
>   clickable when run() finishes.

That is happening cause you are executing your run method in the same thread as the gui. [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You may interested in `SwingWorker` that it's designed for long running task in a background thread. If you want to interrupt you can use `SwingWorker#cancel()`. Read more [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [Cancelling background threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have read the links you sent me and fixed the problem. I simply had to have run() method run on an instance of SwingWorker, and any thing related to GUI on EDT.

Comment: @Dave yep you put in `doInBackground` that runs in another thread that is not the EDT , consider accepting the answer if it was useful! :D

Comment: I am not quite sure about pausing the run() method. When I cancel the SwingWorker thread, is there a way to restart it without creating a new instance of it or am I approaching this in a wrong way?